# Manipulating UIImageView During Animation with CAKeyframeAnimation

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, cakeyframeanimation

I need to move object (UIImageView) from point A to point B, then rotate image at point B by 180 degrees to face the opposite direction and move object from B to A (backwards).

I have the code below which moves from A to B. I also know how to rotate UIImageView. But how to know when object has reached point B and how to apply rotation action considering there are many objects on the screen?

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation    animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
pathAnimation.duration = speed;
pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO; 
CGMutablePathRef pointPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(pointPath, NULL, rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pointPath, NULL, x, y);
pathAnimation.path = pointPath;
CGPathRelease(pointPath);   
[imageView.layer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:[NSString    stringWithFormat:@"pathAnimation%@",objId]];
[imageView release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a delegate on the CAAnimation object, and in the delegate implement the `animationDidStop:finished:` method.

OTOH, the animation you described sounds like it could be done easily enough with UIView's animation support. See [Animating Views with Blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW108) if you're targeting 4.0 and up, or [Animating Views](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW62) if you're still targeting earlier versions.

Comment: I actually have a complex path to move through. For simplicity I use A and B. YOu mention CGAnimation but I do not have that object initialized. I will research how to do it. Thanks

Comment: @Vad: I meant CAAnimation, which is a superclass of CAKeyframeAnimation. Apple has too many different little prefixes for their classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CAAnimation delegate method

```
-(void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag
```